# User identity in shared script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

According to this http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/gGTd0uhh2Kw i can't use Session.getUser().getUserLoginId() to get users identity. How can I know than which user is currently using my script?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

and to retrieve the information just send you a mail with that information

```
MailApp.sendEmail("youemailadress", "Hu? someone is using my scipt!", "this is: "+Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```